# Inserting single character in only one column

Tags: tables, symbols, columns

I just want to know how to insert a single character like `$` in only one column of a table.

To be precise I don't want that character in my heading, but in all other data rows of the corresponding column. I tried it by using `{\@$}`, but it didn't help me much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  And the answer is `\$` most probably

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go, with `array` and its modifier `>{…}` that allows to insert commands at the beginning of each cell of a column. It allows  here to insert the `$` sign in each cell of the second column, and the number of the rows in the first column.

I also use `makecell` to have easy common formatting of column heads, and variable width horizontal rules:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pf]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\addtocounter{tabenum}{1}\color{IndianRed3}\sffamily\footnotesize\thetabenum}
\begin{tabular}{>{\tabitem}l>{\color{DarkSeaGreen4}\sffamily\$}lccc}
\Xcline{2-5}{0.8pt}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \thead{Head 1} & \thead{Head 2} & \thead{Head 3} \\
\cline{2-5}
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
\Xcline{2-5}{.8pt}
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]